# Is it possible to disable Wrap-around for Numpy Number Types

Tags: python, numpy

I would like for example `uint` types to hit 0 rather than wrap-around on subtraction - is it possible to alter this behaviour from python without writing a new c-type? (For example for subtracting two `uint8` numpy arrays) ?

Comment: This is because of behaviour at a much lower level than Python already!

Comment: I'll edit, I think I was unclear, I mean to alter the low-level behaviour from python. i.e. Something like changing one of the arrays to int16, than zeroing all the negative values after subtraction is going to be quite inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

There is no integer overflow/underflow detection in Numpy, but you could test for this yourself either before or after the calculation.  `m0` does this after the calculation, as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

a = np.arange(0, 251, 50, dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.array(a[::-1])

def m0(a, b):
    x = (a-b)
    x[b>a] = 0

def m1(a, b):
    c = (a.astype(np.int16) - b).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

m0(a, b)
m1(a, b)

a = np.array(a.repeat(1000))  # repeat and copy (copy since I don't remember whether repeat is an indexing trick)
b = np.array(b.repeat(1000))

N = 1000000
print timeit.timeit("m0(a, b)", setup="from __main__ import m0, m1, a, b", number=N)
# 1.7734951973
print timeit.timeit("m1(a, b)", setup="from __main__ import m0, m1, a, b", number=N)
# 3.6973798275
```

I also compare the times to @Qlaus's approach, which is also good, and they are comparable (you shouldn't take the 50% speed gain here very seriously, but instead test them both for your specific application).  On the other hand, the subtraction itself takes about `0.6` of the times above, so with this removed, the `m0` solution is about 3x faster.  But on the other hand, usually if you do one operation that will underflow or overflow you will be doing several, and for those cases, using `int16` wil likely be fastest.  In the end, testing for your actual case will be the best approach to optimizing.

Answer (score 3):

Numpy does not do overflow handling on array types. See [this](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2009-April/041691.html) discussion or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970680/integer-overflow-in-numpy-arrays) related question.

If you do not care about speed so much you could save your results in an `int16` first and then clip it and write it back to an `uint8` array.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(5, dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.ones(5, dtype=np.uint8) * 2
print(a-b)  # [254 255   0   1   2]

c = (a.astype(np.int16) - b).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
print(c)  # [0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: And if it turned out you did need that speed, what would be the alternatives, adding a c-type with a check on each basic operation to floor or max when it would otherwise wrap?

Comment: @user3467349 that is going to be a problem for speed, as your new type has to check every operation for over/underflow.

Comment: @user3467349: That would be digging deeper into numpy internals than I feel comfortable. I can't help you there sorry.

Comment: @jonrsharpe more of a problem than a conversion to int16 and back to uint8?

Comment: @user3467349 not sure. The other option is to mask based on the values in the array being subtracted that are larger than the values in the matrix being subtracted from, but that could be slower still.

Answer (score 0):

You can use opencv, which does not overflow. Example:

```
a=np.array([[255]], dtype=np.uint8)
b = cv2.add(a, 10)

b.__repr__()
>>> 'array([[255]], dtype=uint8)'
```