# Python/Pandas - How to make pandas automatically convert numeric type when needed

Tags: python, pandas

When doing some simple calculation from dataframe object (python 3.5, pandas 0.20.1), pandas is not behaving consistently when the calculated result doesn't fit the current numeric type. Why?

Please see code below, creating a dataframe with numeric type-int16 :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': [313], 'col2': [5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d,dtype=np.int16)

print(df.dtypes)

#col1    int16
#col2    int16
#dtype: object

df['col1'] *= 1000000
df['col2'] *= 10000

print(df.dtypes)

#col1    int32
#col2    int16
#dtype: object
```

As you can see, since the upper limit of int16 is 32767, the result of both 313*1000000 and 5*10000 would exceed the upper limit. However, it seems like pandas only automatically converted the result of the first calculation to int32 (which makes sense and is ideal for me) but still kept the result of the second calculation as int16 (which made the result wierd and not ideal for me).

Is there a way to always make pandas automatically convert the numeric type when needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a numpy issue/design choice ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1970697/1562285)). There is still an open numpy github [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/593)

The reason `col1` did change to another `dtype` is probably because the other factor in the product didn't fir in `int16`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that np.int16 has a negative range: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html.

> int16 Integer (-32768 to 32767)  which means 65535 integers

If you only work with positive integers use: `uint16` instead and it will automatically conver both to `uint32`

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': [1], 'col2': [1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d,dtype=np.uint16)

df['col1'] *= 65535  # as np.uint16 can hold 65535 values this will work
df['col2'] *= 65536  # this won't!

print(df.dtypes)

#col1    uint16
#col2    uint32
#dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just tested something out and don't feel using uint could really solve this problem. If you change the value of col2 from 1 to 65535 and then run the code in your answer, you would see that your second calculation would give some strange result.