# how does numpy.astype(np.uint8) convert a float array? -1.2997805 became 255

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.5

this is an execution in ipython3

```
In [81]: r2
Out[81]: 
array([-1.2997805, -1.4251276, -1.3047135, ..., -2.0358603, -1.9741256,
       -1.6412157], dtype=float32)

In [82]: r2.astype(np.uint8)
Out[82]: array([255, 255, 255, ..., 254, 255, 255], dtype=uint8)
```

how is -1.2997805 converted to 255?

ADD : from the comments below(thanks), I tested like this. looks like the float is converted to int, and the modulo 255 (to read it as unsigned int8) is done.

```
is first convereted to int. and the it is cut using modulo(%).  
In [98]: b
Out[98]: array([-1.,  0.,  1.])

In [99]: b.astype(np.uint8)
Out[99]: array([255,   0,   1], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integer overflow in numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970680/integer-overflow-in-numpy-arrays)

Comment: @MykolaZotko doesn't answer this specific case which has to do with how numpy does unsafe casts

Comment: `uint8` type covers the range from 0 to 255. Negative values that are out of this range become 255.

Comment: try it in C and see if it does the same thing. my guess is that first it converts to signed integer as -1 then unsigned as 255.

Comment: @MykolaZotko doesn't explain why -2 is 254.

Comment: Hey,all! thanks, I think @qwr 's guess is right. See the updated post above.

Comment: Obviously this is unspecified behavior and do not rely on it in code. Or maybe numpy says it uses specific casting rules somewhere. I didn't see it

Comment: this code(scheme) was from another company, and it is relying on the fact the original float output is converted to a very small integer when it is positive, while the negative values are turned into a big value(near 255). From the big array, only small area had positive values. Now I can figure out why he did this. (the values had range from - 1.xxx to + 1.xxx)

Comment: @qwr if you post your guess as an answer, I can select it.  And Mykola, my question was why the value is truncated/converted like that. I needed exact explanation. :)

Comment: I will post as an answer if I can find better evidence

Comment: I cannot find a reference on how numpy does casting and I have not looked through the source code. Someone who knows numpy better will be able to give a better answer. It is worth asking a separate question on how numpy does casting exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an "unsafe cast" according to numpy docs on [`astype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html), meaning "any data conversions may be done". They didn't say how exactly the casting is done and I did not find it in a quick search of the docs, so it may be implementation dependent.

My guess is the following: first the 32 bit float is cast to 8 bit signed integer, which defaults to truncating towards zero, ex. -1.3 becomes -1. Then a cast from unsigned 8 bit integer to 8 bit unsigned integer, giving a value of 255. Something like

```
float x = -1.2997805;  # Assume float is 32-bit
(uint8_t)(int8_t)x;
```

This is not the same as directly converting to 8-bit unsigned int with `(uint8_t)x`, which gives 0 at least on the platform I tested on (godbolt's x86-64 gcc).

This kind of thing is [very confusing](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) and may even be platform dependent (possibly depending on what OS, numpy version, what the FP hardware decides to do or if the processor even uses 2s complement, etc) so do not ever rely on this behavior without knowing exactly what platform you will be running the code on, and it is poor coding practice anyway. Surprisingly, I couldn't find a reference on exactly how numpy's casting rules work.

Answer (score 4):

You converted to unsigned int 8, where -1 correspond to 255, -2 to 254 etc.
If you want to get -1, -2 you have to convert it to signed int8 using np.int8:

```
>>> np.float32(-2.0358603).astype(np.uint8)
254                                        
>>> np.float32(-2.0358603).astype(np.int8) 
-2
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already solve and explain the problem. I can however suggest an alternative that may be practically useful:

```
np.uint8(np.clip(x, 0, 255))
```

where x is your floating-type array.

This method ensures negative numbers become 0, and huge positive numbers (> 255) become 255.

For example

```
>>> x = [223.2, 888.2, -32, 255.3, 255]
>>> np.uint8(np.clip(x, 0, 255))
array([223, 255,   0, 255, 255], dtype=uint8)
```