# Why does Python sum() & np.sum() of integers differ?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Why does Python `sum()` & `np.sum()` of integers return different results for (not so) big numbers?

I know there are precision differences when it comes to floats or doubles. But NumPy would also return a completely different summation result for `int32`.

Why is the NumPy result so different from the previous two?
What is happening in example #3?

```py
import functools
import operator
import numpy as np

small_l = range(0, 1000)
big_l = range(0, 100000)

# example #1
functools.reduce(operator.add, small_l)  # result = 499500
functools.reduce(operator.add, big_l)  # result = 4999950000

# example #2
sum([i for i in small_l])  # result = 499500
sum([i for i in big_l])  # result = 4999950000

arr_small = np.array(small_l)
arr_big = np.array(big_l)

# example #3
np.sum(arr_small)  # result = 499500
np.sum(arr_big)  # result = 704982704 why?


# additional check-up
np.sum(arr_big, axis=0)  # result = 704982704
arr_big.dtype  # dtype('int32')
np.sum(big_l)  # result = 704982704
```

Comment: Are you running this in a Jupyter environment? Can you please use variables and print-statements so that normal Python users can also run it?

Comment: Max `np.int32` is *2147483647*. The sum overflows. Try `np.array([4999950000], np.int32)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970680/integer-overflow-in-numpy-arrays

Comment: You don't need to convert the whole array to int64. It's sufficient to tell sum() that the result should be int64: `np.sum(big_l, dtype="int64")`