# Are there any limitations of np.dot() function in numpy library?

Tags: python, list, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have two vectors or arrays with one million elements each(all are positive). I want to find their dot product. When I use python lists to find them I get some big 20 - 30 digit answer. When using numpy arrays with np.dot() function I am getting a negative answer. The code is shown below. Kindly explain your solution.

Code:

```
# Python lists
arr1 = list(range(1000000))
arr2 = list(range(1000000, 2000000))

# Numpy arrays
arr1_np = np.array(arr1)
arr2_np = np.array(arr2)

# Dot product using lists
result = 0
for x1,x2 in zip(arr1,arr2):
    result+=x1*x2
print(result)

# Dot product using numpy built in function np.dot()
print(np.dot(arr1_np,arr2_np))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS3GI.png)

Comment: Hello, https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/ shows equal values, so i am guessing that your results are os or interpreter related issues

Comment: @prakashin, do restart your kernel and try once. Also, please add some details around python version, numpy version, OS details etc. I am unable to reproduce the issue you are facing at my end.

Comment: You're on Windows, and NumPy is using the `np.int32` dtype by default for integer data, so you're encountering integer overflow. Others aren't seeing the issue because they're on operating systems that use `np.int64` by default for integer data. There should be a suitable duplicate question somewhere - integer overflow in NumPy is a frequent source of confusion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integer overflow in numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970680/integer-overflow-in-numpy-arrays)

Comment: @MarkDickinson I have converted np.int32 to np.int64 and the problem still exists

Comment: @Avo Asatryan Yes I tried implementing the code in online based python compiler and it is showing no error. How do I fix the os or interpreter related issues?

Comment: @PRASHINPARIKH: Where and how did you do that conversion? Please show your code.

Comment: @MarkDickinson # Python lists
arr1 = list(range(1000000))
arr2 = list(range(1000000, 2000000))

# Numpy arrays
arr1_np = np.array(arr1)
arr2_np = np.array(arr2)

# Dot product using lists
result = 0
for x1,x2 in zip(arr1,arr2):
    result+=x1*x2
print(result)

# Dot product using numpy built in function np.dot()
# Getting error in this one 
# np_result = (np.dot(arr1_np,arr2_np).astype(np.int64))
np_result = (np.dot(arr1_np,arr2_np).astype(object))
print(np_result)
print(type(np_result))

Comment: @PRASHINPARIKH: Yep, that won't work. You're converting the already overflowed *result* to a larger integer type. By the time you do the conversion, the overflow has already happened. You need to convert the *inputs* to the operation. Use `arr1_np = np.array(arr1, dtype=np.int64)`, and similarly for `arr2`.