# Numpy vectorize seems to "round" number to nearest integer: why?

Tags: python, numpy

It seems that vectorize from numpy rounds number from float to integer and I don't get why.

Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np

def epsilon(n):
    return 1.6952445781450207*2**(-1.028148909051717*n)

def pPsi(n):
    return 1.0577183294485202*2**(-1.028620169094481*n)

def perrMaxFunc(n):
    res=epsilon(n)/(2*np.abs(1/2**n-pPsi(n)))
    return min([1,res])

vectorized_perr=np.vectorize(perrMaxFunc)

nmax=500;

perrMax=vectorized_perr([i for i in range(nmax)])
print(perrMax)
print(perrMaxFunc(500))
```

All the elements of perrMax are either 1 or 0. The last one is for instance equal to 0 while it should be equal to perrMaxFunc(500)~4.91e-5.

Hence, it seems the vectorize function somehow rounds to the nearest integer the output of perrMaxFunc and I don't understand why.

Why is the code doing this?

Comment: I don't know enough about this to write a full answer, but have you tried using `vectorized_perr=np.vectorize(perrMaxFunc, 'f')` ?

Comment: The issue is `return min([1,res])` you should use `return min([1.0,res])` instead

Comment: read what `vectorize` says about `otypes` and a trial calculation.

Comment: You also have an issue with `2**n`. Once `n` reaches 32 or 64 (most likely 64), `2**n` is an overflown integer, wrongly interpreted as 0. At least with `int64` numbers (in pure python `2**64` is `18446744073709551616`, because python is not limited to 64 bits as far as integers are concerned. But numpy use fixed size, 64 bits probably on your machine. So `np.array(2)**64` is 0)

Comment: So, altogether `def perrMaxFunc(n):` `res=epsilon(n)/(2*np.abs(1/2.0**n-pPsi(n)))` `return min([1.0,res])

Comment: Both are errors (the 1.0 and 2.0). But because first results are taken from the `1` not from the computation (because first values are greater than 1), it the the `1` that makes the type for `vectorized`.

Comment: But the `2.0` becomes important for my next remark: you should reconsider use vectorized at all. It is usually a bad idea. As said by its own documentation. Vectorized is very inefficient. It is basically just a `for` loop. Sure, the `for` loop is done in C rather than in python. So you gain a bit CPU in the computation of the iteration themselves (that is i n the `i++` and `i<nmax` evaluations). But the `perrMaxFunc` remains pure python, and remains evaluated one by one.

Comment: Which, in your case, is quite frustrating, because your function is already vectorized, or almost so. Just `def perrMaxFunc(n):` `res=epsilon(n)/(2*np.abs(1/2.0**n-pPsi(n)))` `return np.where(res<1,res,1)`

Comment: And then, no vectorize needed. You can call `perrMaxFunc` either with a number or an array. And if you do call it with array, computation is vectorized (C codes handle everything by batch: `2.0**n` is evaluated on the 500 numbers of array `n`, the so is `1/2.0**n`, then so is `pPsi(n)` and `epsilon(n)`, then...)

Comment: It's not rounding; it's truncating, writing a float value to an int dtype array.  Here's it's because the trial result is an integer, `1`.  But you can get this kind of truncation in other ways.

Comment: you shouldn't be using `numpy.vectorize` at all here. It is frankly rarely a good choice, but certainly not here.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the issue lies in the data type.

Consider the following example:

```
2**np.array(32)
0

2**np.array(32.0)
4294967296.0
```

you can clearly see that the value is 0 in the case of having an `int32`. That is because the number is bigger than could be stored in 32bits. In other languages ie C/C++ this would be an overflow since with a 32-bit signed integer, the maximum representable value is 2<sup>31</sup> − 1. To overcome this, use `int64` or float as your data type.
Consider reading mode regarding [numpy integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970680/integer-overflow-in-numpy-arrays)-- Something that does not exist in python integers  since they automatically upgrade to python long integers when they overflow.

Options:

- Change the `2` to `2.0`
- ensure you pass a float into your function ie `n` must be a float.

Will use the first option:

Here is a work around. Also i used `np.minimum` instead of `np.min` to avoid using `np.vectorize`:

```
import numpy as np

def epsilon(n):
    return 1.6952445781450207*2.**(-1.028148909051717*n)

def pPsi(n):
    return 1.0577183294485202*2.**(-1.028620169094481*n)

def perrMaxFunc(n):
    res = epsilon(n)/(2.*np.abs(1/2.**n-pPsi(n)))
    return np.minimum(1,res)


nmax= n500;

perrMax=perrMaxFunc(np.arange(nmax))
print(perrMax)
print(perrMaxFunc(500))
```