# Difference between Math.prod() and numpy.prod() functions

Tags: python, numpy, math

I was solving one question from [code wars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/57f780909f7e8e3183000078/train/python) where i need to multiply all elements of array/list.
in for few arrays i found numpy.prod function is showing 0 as result and math.prod() was working fine.
Why is it happening, Please tell me some one.

***-Code-***

```
import numpy as np
import math as mt
n =  [943, 129, 891, 767, 363, 837, 948, 451, 469, 250, 754, 638, 212, 484, 871, 812, 373, 164, 367, 405, 457, 837, 956, 344, 137, 982, 750, 699, 779, 395, 490, 636, 60, 511, 610, 957, 951, 802, 304, 771, 896, 289, 786, 228, 991, 596, 734, 68, 171, 633, 361, 955, 158, 516, 117, 978, 960, 393, 487, 520, 822, 740, 563, 729, 983, 493, 897, 392, 24, 110, 474, 380, 800, 904, 566, 279, 632, 87, 111, 735, 423, 195, 927, 642, 203, 721, 520, 272, 10, 198, 314, 436, 707, 601, 919, 964, 928, 775, 720, 505, 605, 777, 726, 625, 13, 755, 519, 225, 695, 256, 693, 636, 221, 981, 475, 743, 839, 759, 179, 907, 135, 429, 929, 411, 718, 291, 204, 112, 52, 830, 415, 442, 15, 345, 928, 214, 774, 615, 539, 67, 64, 390, 147, 54, 199, 641, 626, 376, 668, 105, 265, 97, 705, 447, 57, 728, 914, 546, 407, 595, 670, 848, 661, 231, 407, 340, 572, 490, 712, 873, 993, 391, 394, 556, 192, 223, 606, 850, 248, 31, 948, 956, 818, 905, 760, 39, 765, 930, 891, 735, 809, 915, 168, 313, 531, 995, 865, 574, 575, 357, 977, 372, 859, 790, 455, 280, 232, 454, 262, 480, 328, 217, 685, 94, 501, 994, 290, 643, 894, 640, 577, 189, 276, 580, 506, 853, 234, 573, 650, 734, 345, 717, 690, 524, 488, 256, 532, 95, 840, 498, 337, 236, 140, 381, 813, 406, 888, 817, 907, 1000, 234, 891, 149, 140, 874, 886, 628, 852, 936, 927, 720, 799, 155, 667, 928, 476, 929, 454, 178, 294, 635, 965, 117, 391, 274, 595, 971, 376, 47, 302, 960, 737, 195, 945, 322, 826, 885, 471, 438, 246, 165, 616, 390, 901, 155, 820, 908, 826, 749, 229, 453, 361, 416, 984, 601, 885, 363, 976, 698, 287, 291, 584, 932, 647, 515, 303, 772, 22, 694, 214, 110, 522, 111, 506, 337, 536, 864, 633, 387, 328, 965, 277, 818, 873, 611, 525, 682, 992, 426, 523, 630, 107, 99, 584]
print("Numpy : ",np.prod(n))
print("Maths : ",mt.prod(n))
```

***-Result-***

```
Numpy :  0
Maths :  9575665864810493844667714567444798316205216468142095832649601936629764520270887668646481379389194147905331211758346524539262213670625412244024619091515692719252967714866526789639982772239704213515684602761660702249034021236662153349265727972389557221555445232297033724556787723408401708640747651267620102089898942014077100325570468634529981473248956003154207596171124685882714627577896952180619050139544098351500113466815298558108414453940308828762824118553117486769907457272507063968884583760468547778133850807288783239096992690137056397021722007347391417239975328700917044741805620734206838042081115366334253785922243447147624758597525029948657966966120485226799240493034346020198237595584699908112730872008595256528060608874997455975932768144502885012138842958714015668546266076271308048729163830394880000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

[image]

Comment: This occurs due to integer overflow in numpy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970680/integer-overflow-in-numpy-arrays

Comment: Print out products of the slices of `n` and see when it starts overflowing. On my machine it starts from `n[:4]`: `for i in range(1, len(n)): print(f"{i}\nNumpy : {np.prod(n[:i])}\nMaths : {mt.prod(n[:i])}\n")`